# How do I set a VPC in AWS to 'default VPC' = true?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one VPC set up in AWS, but Default VPC is set to 'false'.

How can i change it to true, and make it the default VPC?

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible:

The introductory blog post [Amazon EC2 Update - Virtual Private Clouds for Everyone!](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/03/amazon-ec2-update-virtual-private-clouds-for-everyone.html) outlines in section *Default VPCs for (Almost) Everyone* that *"The default VPC features are available to new AWS customers and existing customers launching instances in a Region for the first time"*.

Furthermore this is indirectly confirmed by the information within [Your Default VPC and Subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html), see [Deleting Your Default VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#deleting-default-vpc) in particular:

> You can delete your default VPC just as you can delete any other VPC.
>   **However, after you've deleted your default VPC, it's gone**. Now, you
>   must specify a subnet in another VPC when you launch an EC2 instance,
>   because you can't launch instances into EC2-Classic. [...]
>
> If you delete your default VPC and then need to restore it, **you can
>   contact AWS Support to have your account reset so that we can create a
>   new default VPC for you**.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

I recall reading somewhere that they might add respective self-service it later on, but can't find it again and vague announcements like this are rather unusual for AWS anyway, so I might be wrong (and wouldn't hold my breath either way).

Comment: And the way to contact AWS support is through the tickets (anything higher than Basic Support level), or through the [support forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30&start=0).

Comment: For people wandering into this, it is now possible to create a Default VPC from the VPC console **Actions > Create Default VPC** in case you end up deleting your original Default VPC. You can also use CloudFormation to do that. This will create a VPC with **Tenancy** as **Default** and **Default VPC** as **Yes**.

Answer (score 9):

As of June 2018 (might have been available earlier) you can create a (new) default VPC by using Actions --> Create Default VPC

[image: Actions -> Create Default VPC in the VPC web console]

Comment: Yes thank you. I see it there as of the date of this comment, "New VPC Experience"

Answer (score 4):

Simple Answer: You cannot

Detailed answer: You can request AWS support to create a default VPC for you in the required CIDR. But you need to make sure that the range of the VPC that you want to be made default is not already created by you in that account.

Basically, you will mention the range and details to the support and they will create it for you.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue, I was unable to create a new VPC as Default-VPC nor was I able to set an existing VPC as Default-VPC (because under Action "Create Default-VPC" was disabled). But the solution is so simple, execute the cmd from CLI and it works. Make sure you have configured "aws configure" in advance.

```
aws ec2 create-default-vpc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set your own as default, and if you delete your default VPC and then create your own, AWS is unable to set that VPC to default too. They have to create the vpc as default. No idea why, this seems a bit restrictive.